# WorksheetFunction.CountIfs giving me a type missmatch error (error #13)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform a CountIfs function where two criteria are met. First a line is "Approved" and second the Appv Date is within the reporting month. The CountIfs works find when only the first criteria exists but when I add the second I get a Type Mismatch error and I am not sure why.

Code:

```
' Declarations
Dim sRoutine As String 'Routine’s Name
Dim lngStatus As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim intRptMnth  As Integer
Dim intRptYr    As Integer
Dim lngAppvDate  As Long

' Initialize Variables
lngLastRow = FindLastRow(strPSR_File, strCCL, 1)
lngStatus = Worksheets(strCCL).Range(FindLoc(strPSR_File, strCCL,"status")).Column
lngAppvDate = Worksheets(strCCL).Range(FindLoc(strPSR_File, strCCL,"Approved Date")).Column

intRptMnth = CInt(CalcRptMnthNum)
intRptYr = CalcRptYr

' Procedure
With Worksheets(strCCL)
CalcPCR_MTD_Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
    Worksheets(strCCL).Range(Cells(2, lngStatus), Cells(lngLastRow, 
    lngStatus)), _
    "=Approved", _
'********ERRORS HERE*****
    Month(Worksheets(strCCL).Range("n2:n3")), _
    intRptMnth)
'************************
End With
```

Comment: Put a dot/period `.` before `Cells` in that formula and rerun.

Comment: @ JNevill Updated row to " Worksheets(strCCL).Range(.Cells(2, lngStatus), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngStatus))" - Still getting same result

Comment: Also add a declaration of your variables up top. `Dim lngStatus as Long` (if they aren't already). Insuring that there is a numeric value and not a range hanging ot in that variable (and others like it)

Comment: @ JNevill I edited the code snippit to show my Declarations, sorry I should have put that in there before

Comment: `Worksheets(strCCL).Range("n2:n3")` returns a 2D 1x2 array. `Month()` expects a single `Date`.

Comment: @GSerg  I had thought that might be an issue. Do you have a recommendation on how I can compare the dates in that range to specified value? IDK how else I could do what I am attempting. BTW I am fairly new at VBA so there is probably a better way to do this

Comment: Create a variant array of the values and loop that using a variable as your counter.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is there a way to do that within the CountIfs? Or are you recommending I recreate the CountIfs functionality with a custom function?

Comment: Amusingly, the function is [documented wrongly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countifs). Documentation suggests there is one range and 29 parameters that are filters for that range. In fact there are pairs of parameters (one range, one filter, the again), just like for the [sheet version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

Comment: @GSerg I noticed that as well when I was trying to fix the problem

Comment: You can bracket the dates by being less than or equal to the end of the month of `intRptMnth` and greater than or equal to the 1 of that same month in countifs.  But one more thing I noticed.  Countifs requires that the ranges be the same size.  Your first range is variable and the second is set.  They must be the same size.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the recommendation. That worked. I will update the code to show the correct function

Comment: @Chris if you got it working, put the new code as an answer and self answer the question.  Do not put the working code in the question.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried but it wouldn't let me answer the question. I will try again.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: You should probably roll back the last two edits to return it to a viable question.  Right now the code in the question works.  It should show the non working code.

Comment: @ScottCraner I rolled back the code to the original to show the Error. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Corrected Code:

```
' Declarations
 Dim sRoutine As String 'Routine’s Name
 Dim lngStatus As Long
 Dim lngLastRow As Long
 Dim intRptMnth  As Integer
 Dim intRptYr    As Integer
 Dim lngAppvDate  As Long

' Initialize Variables
lngLastRow = FindLastRow(strPSR_File, strCCL, 1)
lngStatus = Worksheets(strCCL).Range(FindLoc(strPSR_File, strCCL, "status")).Column
lngAppvDate = Worksheets(strCCL).Range(FindLoc(strPSR_File, strCCL, "Approved Date")).Column

intRptMnth = CInt(CalcRptMnthNum)
intRptYr = CalcRptYr

' Procedure
With Worksheets(strCCL)
CalcPCR_MTD_Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
    Worksheets(strCCL).Range(.Cells(2, lngStatus), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngStatus)), _
    "=Approved", _
    Worksheets(strCCL).Range(.Cells(2, lngAppvDate), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngAppvDate)), _
    ">=" & DateSerial(intRptYr, intRptMnth, 1), _
    Worksheets(strCCL).Range(.Cells(2, lngAppvDate), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngAppvDate)), _
    "<" & DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) _
    )
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show an variant array method:

```
Dim sRoutine As String 'Routine’s Name
Dim lngStatus As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim intRptMnth  As Integer
Dim intRptYr    As Integer
Dim lngAppvDate  As Long

' Initialize Variables
lngLastRow = FindLastRow(strPSR_File, strCCL, 1)
lngStatus = Worksheets(strCCL).Range(FindLoc(strPSR_File, strCCL, "status")).Column
lngAppvDate = Worksheets(strCCL).Range(FindLoc(strPSR_File, strCCL, "Approved Date")).Column

intRptMnth = CInt(CalcRptMnthNum)
intRptYr = CalcRptYr

' Procedure
With Worksheets(strCCL)
    Dim apprv As Variant
    apprv = .Range(.Cells(2, lngStatus), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngStatus)).Value

    Dim dte As Variant
    dte = .Range(.Cells(2, lngAppvDate), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngAppvDate)).Value

    CalcPCR_MTD_Cnt = 0

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(apprv, 1) To UBound(apprv, 1)
        If apprv(i, 1) = "Approved" And Month(dte(i, 1)) = intRptMnth And Year(dte(i, 1)) = intRptYr Then CalcPCR_MTD_Cnt = CalcPCR_MTD_Cnt + 1
    Next i

End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the variant array answer. I didn't test this to verify it worked but I appreciate you showing the methodology.